# Saving right handside of an equation in r

Tags: r

I want save the following expression in r

```
 DA<-   b0 + b1 * x1 + b4 * x4 + b5 * x5 + b6 * x6 + b8 * x8 +
      b9 * x9 + b10 * x10 + b11 * x11 + b12 * x12 + b13 * x13 + b15 * x15 +
      b17 * x17 + b18 * x18 + b19 * x19 + b20 * x20 + b21 * x21 + b25 * x25 + b27 * x27 + bl2 * d2 + bl3 *
      d3 + bl5 * d5 + bl6 * d6 + bl7 * d7 +  bl8 * d8 + bl9 * d9 + bl10 * d10 + bl11 * d11
```

Here all elements starting with a `b` are estimated coefficients and `x`is a column in the dataframe. I want `DA` to appear in the log likelihood expression as

`sum(log((pnorm(DA)^y)*((1-pnorm(DA))^(1-y))))`

Unfortunately r does not let me save `DA` and gives `Error: object 'b0' not found`, hence I cannot estimate the log likelihood function. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: Are you looking for `as.formula()`?

Comment: Tried that does not work. Get the same error.

Comment: Have you defined b0?

Comment: is `DA <- quote(...)` what you want? then you can `eval(DA)` or `sum(log((pnorm(eval(DA))^y)*((1-pnorm(eval(DA)))^(1-y))))`

Comment: "all elements starting with a b are estimated coefficients" How are these stored? Is there no `predict` method for whichever model you have fit there?

Comment: @rawr Thank you for the suggestion. `quote(...)` is exactly what I was looking for.